# how I can add the icon of my iOS App in the native Phone app’s Contacts with CallKit

Tags: ios, callkit

I want to add the icon of my iOS app in the phone contacts like WhatsApp and make the Click to To direct to my application Knowing that I use Callkit. Any help ?